# Telegram bot with thread throws exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, telegram-bot

I have two projects and a piece of code. 
In one of them everything works good, but in the another one I get this error. 
How could I solve this?

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunBot));
    botThread.Start();
}

private void RunBot()
{
    bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(Token);

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "online";
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        btnStart.BackColor = Color.Red;
        btnStart.Text = "stop";
    }));


    int offset = 0;

    botIsRun = true;
    while (botIsRun)
    {
        Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates;
        try
        {
            updates =bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erorr", "Error");
            botIsRun = false;
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Offline";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                btnStart.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                btnStart.Text = "stop";
            }));
            continue;
        }



        foreach (var update in updates)
        {

            offset = update.Id + 1;

            if (update.Message == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            string text = update.Message.Text.ToLower();
            var from = update.Message.From;
            var chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;

            var a = update.Message.NewChatMembers;


            if (text.Contains("/start"))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("welcome " + from.Username)
                    .AppendLine("fromId: " + from.Id)
                    .AppendLine("From IsBot: " + from.IsBot)
                    .AppendLine("From LanguageCode: " + from.LanguageCode)
                    .AppendLine("From LastName: " + from.LastName)
                    .AppendLine("From SupportsInlineQueries: " + from.SupportsInlineQueries)
                    .AppendLine("From FirstName: " + from.FirstName)
                    .AppendLine("From CanJoinGroups: " + from.CanJoinGroups)
                    .AppendLine("From CanReadAllGroupMessages: " + from.CanReadAllGroupMessages);

                bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at TelegramBot.FrmMain.RunBot() in C:\Users\MSP\Desktop\Telegram bot\project\TelegramBot\TelegramBot\FrmMain.cs:line 59

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are mixing Sync with Async code, you should convert `private void RunBot()` to `private async Task RunBotAsync()`, otherwise you are losing the exception in `updates =bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;` (also, I leave you a couple of comments about thing you should have into account):

```cs
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Convert your old [Thread botThread] variable to [Task botTask]
    botTask = RunBotAsync;    //Don't worry, as RunBot() is now async, it will not block your ui
}

private async Task RunBotAsync()
{
    bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(Token);

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "online";          //YOu shoul check this part, because accesing Form components here could be risky (becouse the method could be executed in other theread different to the UI thread, then you can get an error)
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        btnStart.BackColor = Color.Red;
        btnStart.Text = "stop";
    }));


    int offset = 0;

    botIsRun = true;
    while (botIsRun)
    {
        Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates;
        try
        {
            updates = await bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erorr", "Error");
            botIsRun = false;
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Offline";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                btnStart.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                btnStart.Text = "stop";
            }));
            continue;
        }



        foreach (var update in updates)
        {

            offset = update.Id + 1;

            if (update.Message == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            string text = update.Message.Text.ToLower();
            var from = update.Message.From;
            var chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;

            var a = update.Message.NewChatMembers;


            if (text.Contains("/start"))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("welcome " + from.Username)
                    .AppendLine("fromId: " + from.Id)
                    .AppendLine("From IsBot: " + from.IsBot)
                    .AppendLine("From LanguageCode: " + from.LanguageCode)
                    .AppendLine("From LastName: " + from.LastName)
                    .AppendLine("From SupportsInlineQueries: " + from.SupportsInlineQueries)
                    .AppendLine("From FirstName: " + from.FirstName)
                    .AppendLine("From CanJoinGroups: " + from.CanJoinGroups)
                    .AppendLine("From CanReadAllGroupMessages: " + from.CanReadAllGroupMessages);

                await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```